# Angular - scrollPositionRestoration on only one route

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I want to disable scrollPositionRestoration on one page. Let's say I have the following routes in my app-routing.module.ts file...

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{ path: 'home', component: myComponent}, { path: 'about', component: myComponent}, ]
```

and I have my imports as follows...

```
@NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
})]
```

How would I disable the scollPositionRestoration on the 'about' route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use: `scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'`

Reset back to:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Then use this in your home.component.ts only:

```
scrollTop() {
    window.scroll(0, 0);
  }
```

Then add `(click)="scrollTop()"` where you want to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You could not control `scrollPositionRestoration` value differently in different routes. This option for root module only. As a result, In your case you should remove it from root module (by default `scrollPositionRestoration` value is `'disabled'`) and can control the position of scroll by `Router` and `ViewportScroller`.
In the `app.component` You can listen navigation events like this:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
  if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    // if (..) You can write any logic for moving the scroll to the top or not
    this.viewport.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
  }
});
```